# React Class Based Higher Order Component Works but not Function based with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

I wrote both a functional as well as a class based higher order component function for React. The class based version works, where as the exact translation of it in functional form with hooks does not work. Can someone explain where I went wrong, both code blocks are mentioned below.

Class Based HOC

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "../components/UI/Modal/Modal";

const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      error: null,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
        this.setState({ error: null });
        return req;
      });
      this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (res) => res,
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error: error.response });
          console.log(error.response)
        }
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);
    }

    errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      this.setState({ error: null });
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Modal showModal={this.state.error ? true : false} error={this.state.error} closeModal={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
            {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
          </Modal>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };
};

export default withErrorHandler;
```

Functional Based HOC

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

import Modal from "../components/UI/Modal/Modal";

const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
      setError(null);
      return req;
    });

    const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (res) => res,
      (err) => {
        setError(err);
      }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        axios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
        axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
      };
    }, [requestInterceptor, responseInterceptor]);

    const errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      setError(null);
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Modal showModal={error ? true : false} closeModal={errorConfirmedHandler}>
          {error ? error.message : null}
        </Modal>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
};

export default withErrorHandler;
```

Comment: The equivalent to ```componentWillUnmount``` would be a ```useEffect```'s return statement with empty dependency array, I think. Try this : ```useEffect(() => {return () => { axios.interceptors.request.eject -----your code--- }, []);```.

Comment: Yes that is right, however it throws an errror when I dont enter the requestInterceptor and responseInterceptor in the dependency array. I tried with an empty dependency array too and that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Also, you didn't pass the ```error``` prop to ```<Modal />```. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes it gets it from props.children